# print out celery settings for django project?

Tags: django, celery

I'd like to know if celery settings specified in the `settings.py` file is actually being recognized.

How can I tell if celery picked up the options?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the [`_conf` object](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/13bd136871d1954a56b5f4300bfdfac396070b1c/celery/app/base.py#L989) on the Celery app instance, after is has been initalised and configured:

```
app = Celery("yourproject")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
print(app._conf)
```